# Hashing with python optimization, hashlib and multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, file, hashcode

I am looking to get any type of improvement, I want to be able to hash a list of 'blocks' aka strings and check if hashes match per block, if you can help me with that, currently reading and writing is optimized as I am writing direct bytes, any type of improvement in performance is appreciated!
I am also looking to use as little ram, when I read the file for confirmation I want to use as little ram as possible.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time as t
from hashlib import sha256


def crypto(args: list):

    block, requests = args
    h = sha256(block).digest
    n = b'\n'
    with open("blocks.txt", "ab") as blocks:
        write = blocks.write
        for i in range(requests):
            write(h() + n)
        blocks.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("")
    print("Program starting... \n")
    last_block, block, counter, requests, threads, confirmed = [], "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()".encode(
        'UTF-8'), 0, 10000000, 3, False
    args = [block, requests]
    print("Clearing blocks.txt...")
    with open("blocks.txt", "wb") as blocks:
        blocks.write(b"")
        blocks.close()
    print("Cleared blocks.txt... \n")
    print("Starting the pool...")
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=threads)
    print("Pool has started... \n")
    start_time = t.perf_counter()
    print("Starting the hashing...")
    p.map(crypto, [args] * threads)
    p.close()
    print("Hashed all requests... \n")
    time = t.perf_counter() - start_time
    print("Checking confirmation cycle...")
    with open("blocks.txt", "rb") as blocks:
        data = blocks.readlines()
        for sha in data:
            if data[0] == sha:
                confirmed = True
            else:
                print(f"**Invalid Confirmation:{sha}**")
                confirmed = False
                break
        blocks.close()
        confirm = t.perf_counter() - time
    print("Checked the confirmation cycle... \n")
    if confirmed:
        print("Valid confirmation cycle! \n")
    else:
        print("Invalid confirmation cycle! \n")
    print(
        f"Total time to process the {requests} requests with {threads} confirmations: {time}.")
    print(
        f"Average hashes per second per confirmation thread: {requests / time}."
    )
    print(f"Time to check if confirmations are legal: {confirm}.")
```

Comment: What would `crypto()` actually do in the real world?  Currently there's a trivial speedup by not computing the same block hash a very large number of times, but I'm presuming it will be hashing *different* blocks---i.e. you're not trying to stress test python's sha256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An alternative algorithm

I do not quite know what you want to do, and so this might miss.  But I am presuming that you are not trying to stress-test `sha256` by hashing the same block a zillion times and checking it works, and thus your `h()`, which always returns the same thing, would be better modelled as something like this:

```py
from random import randint

def randomfail_hasher(block):
    if randint(0, 100_000_000) < 2:
        return sha256(block + b"Some other data").digest()
    else:
        return sha256(block).digest()
```

Note that you can write very long numbers like this: `100_000_000_000` which is *extremely* useful if you are not very good at counting large numbers of zeros, like me.  (Before I knew that I used to do ugly things like `int(1E9)`.)

Per your comments on the SO question, you want the whole thing to bail the moment a match doesn't happen.  Although you apparently want to keep the hashes, I can't see any reason to do that as they are either the same as the correct target or not, so we are just duplicating the same values.

Here is my `crypto` function:

```py
class ValidationError(Exception):
    pass

def crypto(args):
    block, requests, correct = args
    for candidate in (randomfail_hasher(block) for _ in range(requests)):
        if candidate != correct:
            raise ValidationError(candidate)
```

This does the hashing and validation in one step, for a given target.  It throws if validation ever fails.

As I understand it, the entire pool has *one* target (certainly that's currently true).  So we want to kill the whole pool if anything fails.  For this I use an explicitly named callback function (a lambda would be fine, but this is clearer and you may want to do something else:

```py
def die(_):
    p.terminate()
```

And then I use `map_async`:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    block = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()".encode(
        "UTF-8"
    )
    requests = 10_000_000
    threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=threads)

    start_time = t.perf_counter()
    print("Starting the hashing...")

    correct = sha256(block).digest()
    try:
        res = p.map_async(
            crypto, [(block, requests, correct)] * threads, error_callback=die
        )
        res.get()
        p.close()
        print("Success")
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(f"Failed: {e}")

    time = t.perf_counter() - start_time

    print(
        f"Total time to process the {requests} requests with {threads} confirmations: {time}."
    )
```

I have changed a few other things here:

- we have as many threads as cpus, which is probably right for a hashing problem
- I assign variables directly, rather than unpacking a tuple (!)
- I use immutables (tuples) instead of lists.

#### Timings

On my machine, your code took (with 6 rather than 3 threads for the cpus here):

```
Total time to process the 10000000 requests with 6 confirmations: 11.103364465001505.
Average hashes per second per confirmation thread: 900627.916116833.
Time to check if confirmations are legal: 92861.462768207.
```

Replacing lists with tuples, removing redundant `close()` got

```
Total time to process the 10000000 requests with 6 confirmations: 10.663555920997169.
Average hashes per second per confirmation thread: 937773.4851382372.
Time to check if confirmations are legal: 93723.683743126.
```

That's probably significant, but I didn't repeat it.

The alternative algorithm here takes ~34 seconds to validate everything, and is of course *much* cheaper in the event of a failure.

If you mean to test *different targets* for each thread that is perfectly possible too, and will still be faster than writing and reading.  You can write the *target* hashes to disk if you really need to.